# Improve quality of audio recorded in .wav format swift

Tags: ios, swift, avaudiorecorder

So I'm trying to record an audio in swift using AVAudioRecorder. This is the code that I'm working with to make the recording:

```
try session.setCategory(AVAudioSession.Category.playAndRecord, options: .defaultToSpeaker)
   try session.setActive(true)
   let settings = [
       AVFormatIDKey: kAudioFormatLinearPCM,
       AVSampleRateKey: 44100,
       AVNumberOfChannelsKey: 2,
       AVEncoderAudioQualityKey:AVAudioQuality.max.rawValue
   ] as [String : Any]
   audioRecorder = try AVAudioRecorder(url: getFileUrl(), settings: settings)
   audioRecorder.delegate = self
   audioRecorder.isMeteringEnabled = true
   audioRecorder.prepareToRecord()
```

I need the audio to be in .wav format and to have the best quality possible. I wanna know what are the best setting to achieve that

Comment: If you didn't want an apple lossless file, you should not have specified an apple lossless file. If you _did_ want an apple lossless file, then you can convert it later to an aiff. I don't quite get the point, though; both apple lossless and wav are lossless, so I don't see why apple lossless is "the best option".

Comment: Why is the sampling rate set to 44100 if you want a good quality?

Comment: @matt That's what I found. I'm not sure if it improves at some point the quality or not. What do you think I should use?

Comment: @ElTomato what do you recommend me to use?

Comment: I don't know if your question is about how to improve audio quality or about how to save audio as a wav file.

Comment: I need to improve the quality of the audio and I need the file to be .wav. I know using kAudioFormatLinearPCM saves the file as .wav, but what I'm asking is how to improve the quality

Comment: The quality is not going to be better than linear PCM just because you chose apple lossless. Are you under the impression that it is?

Comment: I thought i would get a better quality. Now I know it doesn't. So I guess my question is what sampling rate should I use in order to improve my record quality

Comment: You should use the sampling rate that matches what the hardware gives you. You are not going to magically get any more information than what is actually flowing in.